# Raw socket DNS request in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, dns

```
<?php

    $domain = 'www.google.com';
    $dns = '8.8.8.8';
    $timeout = 2;

    $data = rand(10, 77) . "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0";
    $data .= pack('n', '1') . pack('n', '0') . pack('n', '0') . pack('n', '0');

    foreach (explode('.', $domain) as $bit) {
        $l = strlen($bit);
        $data .= chr($l) . $bit;
    }

    $data .= "\0\0" . pack('n', '2') . pack('n', '1');

    $errno = $errstr = 0;
    $fp = fsockopen('udp://' . $dns, 53, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if (!$fp || !is_resource($fp)) return $errno;

    socket_set_timeout($fp, $timeout);
    fwrite($fp, $data);

    var_dump ( fread($fp, 8192) );
    fclose($fp);
```

This is the code I've been trying to get to work. Here is a snippet of the C implmentation of a dns lookup http://www.binarytides.com/dns-query-code-in-c-with-linux-sockets/. I cannot see what I've missed out in the PHP.

As for using dns_get_records, that works but it hasn't got a timeout which is very bad for me because I'm going to be dealing with many lookups/second. Here was my solution `$lookup = shell_exec('dig "' . $cleaned_host . '." -t ANY +nomultiline +nocomments +nonssearch +tcp +nostats +qr +time=1');` but the performance, even with that improvement, is more than double of the speed of dns_get_records which is very bad for my situation. As such, I've attempted a raw socket connection with a DNS server with the assumption that the speed will be of that of dns_get_records.

---

An alternative would be to limit the dns_get_records function via an ini_set such as default_socket_timeout but I cannot find any that will work with it.

An even better solution (which will work with the rest of the script) would be to fetch the cURL dns cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly, what you've failed to spot is that the C code uses nine separate *bitfields* that pack the DNS header flags into a singe 16-bit field, whereas you're trying to append 9 separate bytes.

You should just add `pack('n', 0x0100)` after the random Query ID, so as to set the `RD` (recursion desired) bit.

Also, you should only append a single `\0` after the domain name, to represent the trailing "root" label, or alternatively ensure that every domain name you supply already has a trailing dot such that the `explode` function does that work for you.  This code works:

```
$domain = 'www.google.com.';
$dns = '8.8.8.8';
$timeout = 2;

$data = pack('n6', rand(10, 77), 0x0100, 1, 0, 0, 0);

foreach (explode('.', $domain) as $bit) {
    $l = strlen($bit);
    $data .= chr($l) . $bit;
}

$data .= pack('n2', 2, 1);  // QTYPE=NS, QCLASS=IN
```

Don't forget to refer to [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) to learn how to decode the response properly!

Comment: Brilliant, it works. Thank you. However, I've tried setting QTYPE to 255 (All records), this wont work with certain domain names (presumably because the DNS record haven't been cached), how would a normal nslookup return all records in that situation?

Comment: Yes, that's right - asking a recursive resolver (such as Google's 8.8.8.8) for `QTYPE = ANY` will only trigger an upstream query with the same `QTYPE` if there's nothing already in cache.  If there's anything already in cache you'll just get that instead.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to get this working to return MX records for a domain name.  Can anyone help with that ?  thx

Comment: @MacMan you'd be better off using the builtin `getmxrr` function than trying to use plain UDP sockets.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for the reply, the box I have doesn't have getmxrr support, hence the idea to use sockets.

Comment: @MacMan that seems surprising, since that function has been around since PHP 4, or are you perhaps on Windows where it only appeared in 5.3.2  ?

Comment: @Alnitak I'm running on an old closed source Linux box which has PHP 4.3.10  when I try to use getmxrr I get `
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: getmxrr()`  Thanks

Comment: sounds like you need to ask a new question.  Also, check out the help page for `getmxrr()` which includes links to a PHP implementation of Net::DNS

Comment: Hi! Were you able to ever get this example working? I have been searching forever to find a simple solution to resolve domains to ip addresses with custom DNS servers. My domain uses CNAME to resolve to ip's in the users location (CDN) and I want to make sure my files are stored in those locations. I can manually set the ips, but i'm not sure if or how often they change. I see the Net::DNS thing, but I am unsure of how to get that running. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I needed a code to check if a certain DNS server was delegating the DNS to another server, I've started of from the example above, my final code is:

```php
function has_ns_records( $domain, $dns = 'dns1.nic.blog' ) {
   $timeout = 2;

    // Create a question packet
   $data = pack( 'n6', rand(10, 77), 0x0100, 1, 0, 0, 0 );

   foreach ( explode('.', $domain ) as $part ) {
       $length = strlen( $part );
       $data .= chr( $length ) . $part;
   }

   $data .= pack( 'n2' , 2, 1 );  // QTYPE=NS, QCLASS=IN

   $errno = $errstr = 0;
   $fp = fsockopen( 'udp://' . $dns, 53, $errno, $errstr, $timeout );
   if (!$fp || !is_resource($fp)) return $errno;

   socket_set_timeout( $fp, $timeout );
   fwrite( $fp, $data );

   $response_data = fread( $fp, 8192 );
   fclose( $fp );

   // read answer header
   $ans_header = unpack( "nid/nspec/nqdcount/nancount/nnscount/narcount", substr( $response_data, 0, 12 ) );

   // skip question part
   $offset = strlen( $domain ) + 4 + 2 + 1; // 4 => QTYPE + QCLASS, 2 => len, 1 => null terminator

   $record_header = unpack("ntype/nclass/Nttl/nlength", substr( $response_data, 12 + $offset, 10 ) );

   // Expect type NS and class IN, when domain not exist it returns SOA (6)
   return $record_header[ 'type' ] === 2 && $record_header[ 'class' ] === 1;
}


var_dump( has_ns_records( 'get.blog.' ) );
```

Comment: This is a new question instead of answer. use [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link to ask new question

Comment: Not sure what you mean @ρяσѕρєяK, the code above is a final solution to my specific problem, just wanted to share in case someone else ends up here, like I did.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 0x00 after the query name:

```
    $data = pack( 'n6', rand(10, 77), 0x0100, 1, 0, 0, 0 );
    foreach ( explode('.', $domain ) as $part ) {
        $length = strlen( $part );
        $data .= chr( $length ) . $part;
    }
    $data .= pack( 'H1', 0x00 ); // <---- MUST HAVE THIS 
    $data .= pack( 'n2' , 2, 1 );  // QTYPE=NS, QCLASS=IN
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

There is also a a PHP library which makes RAW calls to DNS servers by default.

Code sample:

```php
// Raw DNS request- TCP

<?php

$dnsHandler = (new TCP())
    ->setPort(53)
    ->setNameserver('8.8.8.8')
    ->setTimeout(3) // limit execution to 3 seconds
    ->setRetries(5); // allows 5 retries if response fails

// Let's initialize the DNS records service
$dnsRecordsService = new DnsRecords($dnsHandler);

// let's get some TXT records from `bluelibraries.com`
$records = $dnsRecordsService->get('bluelibraries.com', RecordTypes::TXT);

// let's display them
print_r($records);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\Types\TXT Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bluelibraries.com
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [class] => IN
                    [type] => TXT
                    [txt] => google-site-verification=kWtestq0tP8Ae_WJhRwUcZoqpdEkvuXJk
                )
        )
    [1] => BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\Types\TXT Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bluelibraries.com
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [class] => IN
                    [type] => TXT
                    [txt] => 55d34914-636b-4x-b349-fdb9f2c1eaca
                )
        )
)
```

**More information at**
https://github.com/bluelibraries/dns

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33723268)